# how can i show that £ is a topology on a set X?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set X={a,b}, and the collection £  given by £={ Ø, {a},{b},X }.               show that £ is a topology on X.

I know that from the definition of topological space i must consider to show the following three axioms

1. To show that both the empty set and X belong to £

2.To show that the intersection of any finite sub-collection of sets in £ belong to £

3.To show that the union of any sub-collection of sets in £ belong to £

For the first axiom,  it is true that both the empty set and X belong to £, and i have no  problem with this.

but my problem lies on second and third axioms,i need to be clear, how can the sub-collections in axioms 1 and 2 be formed?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sub-collection is a collection of sets in $\mathcal{L}$. For example $\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$ is such a collection. it's intersection is empty and it's union is $X$.

Comment: @ Shamovic;can't i form sub-collection like { {a},{a},{b},{b}}?

Comment: Since it is a collection, repetition doesn't matter. Order doesn't matter either.

Answer (score 3):

{a}$\cap${b} = $\emptyset$ and {a}$\cup${b} = {a,b} = X so both are contained within the topology. This together with the obvious intersections and unions with $\emptyset$ and X show that this is a topology.